# creacion de componenete livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

hola estoy tratando de crear un componente en livewire con este comando  php artisan make:livewire FirstComponent pero por alguna razón me lo esta creando fuera de http alguien sabe porque sucede estoy siguiendo la instalación oficial de laravel o la de jetstream [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor pon el código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de mejor manera a resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que estas usando la versión 3 de Liveware.

Si te fijas la documentación de Livewire 3 veraz que uno de los cambios es la carpeta donde se guardan los componentes.

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart

Posiblemente tu tutorial este basado en la versión 2.
Es por eso la diferencia.

Pero funcionaria igual.

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias era eso